# variable available on DOM not displaying marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, flask, handlebars.js, marionette

I have a view with function:

```
function($, OurThings) {
    "use strict";

    var View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        tagName: "div",
        className: "wrapper classname",
        template: Template,
        pageNum: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        totalResults: 0,
        keywords: null,

        ...

        serializeData: function () {
            var data = {};
            data.items = this.model;
            data.planIds = getPlanIds;

            var def_organization = $.Deferred();
            var organization = new Organization();
            organization.getOrganizations(function(response){
                def_organization.resolve(response);
            });

            $.when(
                def_organization
            ).done(
                function(
                    res_organizations
                ) {
                    var organization_list = res_organizations.objects;
                    data.organization_list = organization_list;
                }
            );

            return data;
        }

    });
```

We use handlebars to display the template data. In the template, our-template.tpl:

```
{{#each organization_list }}
    {{id}}
{{/each}}
{{log this }}
{{ log this.organization_list }}
{{ this.organization_list }}
```

Nothing here shows on the page, and only `log this` works. In the console, however, I see my object clearly within `this`:

[image]

I don't get why it prints to console twice, but on the second go around I see organization_list plain as day. To access the sibling of it, `items`, all you have to do is

```
{{#each items}}
   ...do stuff
{{/each}}
```

like normal

I tried adding this object in the `onRender` function and that didn't work, and since `items` is added in `serializeData` I tried it there and now it goes to the DOM, but is not useable. How can I use this object in my handlebars template? Thank you

Comment: I don't think the necessary code is present in order to answer this question. To start, I would add the code that calls the template method.

Comment: alright, I'll look for that and add it